Every natural number has a unique representation in the factorial number system
I want to prove the following proposition:
Let $n$ be a natural number. Then there is a unique representation of the form
$n=c_1\cdot1!+c_2 \cdot 2!+...+c_k \cdot k!$.
Hint: Use the identity:
$\sum_{k=1}^n k \cdot k!=(n+1)! -1$
My idea would be to assume that there are two different representations, and then show that they are in fact the same representation.
Let $n=\sum_{i=1}^k c_i i!$ and $n=\sum_{i=1}^m b_i i!$ be two different representations of $n$.
I will assume that $m \geq k$.
Without loss of generality, by definig $c_{k+1}:=0,...,c_m:=0$, we can write $\sum_{i=1}^k c_i i!$ as $\sum_{i=1}^m c_i i!$.
Then $0=\sum_{i=1}^m b_i i!-\sum_{i=1}^m c_i i!=\sum_{i=1}^m (b_i-c_i) i!$.
Now we can view $0$ as $0 \cdot 1! + ...+ 0 \cdot m!$, thus we get
$b_1=c_1$
$b_2=c_2$
.
.
.
$b_m=c_m$.
The thing that has bothering me is, that I did not use the hint.
Is my solution correct and how would one do this prove with the hint?

You need some restriction on the $c_i$. Otherwise we have $2\cdot1!=1\cdot2!$, so the representation is not unique.

I'm under the impression that $c_i \leq i$

@Karl Right, I need the restriction $0 \leq c_i \leq i$ .

In $0=\sum_{i=1}^m (b_i-c_i)i!$, "the restriction" becomes $-i\le b_i-c_i\le i$. Then you have to prove $0$ still has a unique representation with such restriction.

You should edit the question to state the restriction $0 \leq c_i \leq i$.

Assume two sequences that are not equal. Let them be $\sum^A_{i=1} a_i i!$ and $\sum^B_{i=1} b_i i!$.
Let $a_x$ be the first instance when $a_x \neq b_x$, where we define $a_{A+j}=b_{B+j} = 0$ for $j > 0$. WLOG $a_x > b_x$ and so we have $a_x-b_x \geq 1$.
Notice that we have $$\sum^A_{i=1} a_i i!-\sum_{j=x+1}^A a_jj! \geq a_x x!> (a_x-1)x! + \sum_{k=1}^{x-1} k \cdot k! \geq b_xx! + \sum_{k=1}^{x-1} k \cdot k!$$
$$\geq \sum^B_{i=1} b_i i!-\sum_{j=x+1}^A a_jj!$$
Thus, we have that $$\sum^A_{i=1} a_i i!> \sum^B_{i=1} b_i i!$$
which is a contradiction and we are done.
